# Child window not getting invalidated when the parent window has CLIP_CHILDREN and CLIP_SIBLINGS style

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In my Application, there is a modeless dialog box which has one static control and some customized controls - Edit box, buttons. Actually we are enhancing the functionality of this dialog and added 2 more static controls. The dialog box has CLIP_SIBLINGS and CLIP_CHILDREN styles.

The Problem I am facing is in WinXP, when some other window gets overlapped on this dialog, every other control is getting painted properly except the newly added static controls. But there is no particular difference between the existing static controls and the ones I added.
This is solved with explicitly calling Invalidate method of the static control in dialog's OnPaint() method, but still I didn't get why the existing controls are painted fine.

I tried removing CLIP_CHILDREN style, then it worked fine but there is a lot of flickering. 
Please help me understand the same, I have gone through so many threads relating to the same but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: Is the dialog model or modeless?  If you are custom painting the dialog try using double buffering.